# mosquitto cloudmqtt bridging

Tags: java, mqtt, mosquitto

I want to bridge local mosquitto broker and remote cloudmqtt broker. I want to make a bridge that connects two brokers so all the messages on all topics that are subscribed or published to one broker are visible to another broker, so both brokers can subscribe and publish on the same topics so I configured mosquitto.conf file like this:

```
#Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
#A full description of the configuration file is at
#/usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

connection cloudmqtt
address mnumber.cloudmqtt.com:port
topic # both 0
notifications false
start_type automatic
remote_usename username_of_the_user_on_cloudmqtt
remote_password password_of the_user_on_cloudmqtt

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistance true
persistance_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
```

When I use `mosquitto_sub` and `mosquitto_pub` in the terminal, local broker works fine but the messages are not coming to the cloudmqtt.com broker. And when I use these commands in terminal:

```
mosquitto_sub -h mnumber.cloudmqtt.com -p port -u remote_username -P remote_password -t topic
mosquitto_pub -h mnumber.cloudmqtt.com -p port -u remote_username -P remote_password -t topic -m message
```

messages are coming to cloudmqtt, but nothing comes to terminal in which I wrote `mosquitto_sub - topic`. So I can say that both brokers are working fine but there is no bridge between them, what may be wrong with this?

EDIT: after `sudo /etc/init.d/mosquitto stop` I get:

> [ ok ] Stopping network daemon:: mosquitto

mosquitto is now stopped and when I try use local client I get:

> Error: Connection refused

and then after starting mosquitto with `mosquitto` I get [this log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeQcp.gif), in which I have this

> Warning:Address family not supported by the protocol

is that problem that doesn't allow bridging?

@hardillb What do you mean by distro?

EDIT 2:
I've looked into [log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e271H.gif) (destination /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log) and I've seen that there is a line that says:

```
mosquitto version 1.3.5 (build date 2014-10-18 21:06:44+0100) start$
Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
.
.
.
Socket error on client mosqsub/3739-raspberryp, disconnecting.
.
.
.
```

and when I try `mosquitto --version` in terminal I get:

> unknown option mosquitto --version mosquitto version 1.4.5 (build date
>   Sun, 08 Nov 2015 21:43:12 +0000)

So i tried `sudo apt-get install mosquitto` and I got:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependecy tree Reading state
>   information... Done mosquitto is already the newest version. 
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded 0

How it is possible to have two versions of mosquitto (1.3.5 in log file and 1.4.5 when I try mosquitto --version) and when I try to upgrade I can't, could some of this cause the problem?

EDIT3: have installed raspibian jessie and mosquitto, but the problem is the same there is no bridging. Do I need to set up some port forwarding because local mosquitto is using port 1883, and cloudmqtt uses some other port?

Comment: Is that all that is in you mosquitto.conf file? Also please update the question with the output from when you start mosquitto. I'm guessing it's because mosquitto is not starting a local listener

Comment: Or you have a local firewall that is blocking port 1883

Comment: Please edit the original question as comments do not support formatting text

Comment: @hardillb Thank you, I didn't know how to add pictures in a comment, I edited original question.

Comment: @hardillb mosquitto starts at startup so when I use "mosquitto" command in terminal, I have an error: "address is already in use", because port 1883 is already occupied by mosquitto, any other ideas?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what distro you are using try 'sudo /etc/init.d/mosquitto stop'

Comment: @hardillb I tried to configure bridge to the mosquitto broker on my PC, I commented cloudmqtt configuration in mosquitto.conf file and added these lines:
connection rpi_pc
address 192.168.1.45:1883
topic in_topic in 0
topic out_topic out 0

and that works fine, but there is still the problem with cloudmqtt configuration.